# Load balancers request forwarding after sso call back

Tags: authentication, load-balancing

I have two instances of same application and the load is balanced between two instances using F5 load balancer. Both applications have in memory session storage. Both the instances are using the same SSO authentication provider. Let the address of the load balancer be 'ip1'. Now suppose a user sends the request for first time and is taken to instance1 (by load balancer). Instance 1 redirects user to get authenticated with call back address 'ip1'. Now after authentication I want that callback request should go to same instance using which user was redirected to sso. As the callback address is 'ip1' how load balancers will decide that the request should go to instance1..

Comment: It depends on what methods your LB support.

Comment: I don't know much about load balancers. Can you suggest me some solution.

Comment: Check haproxy..